# Outputting text in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

When I run my unit tests, I would like to print out and read how long it takes to run a function. I tried using Console.WriteLine() and Trace.WriteLine(), but that didn't work. What is the proper method I should be using?

I have the following unit test

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ProductSerializationTest()
{
    Stopwatch swSerialization = new Stopwatch();
    swSerialization.Start();
    SerializeProductsToXML(dummyProductList, XMLFolderPath);
    swSerialization.Stop();
    // Print out swSerialization.Elapsed value
 }
```

Comment: What are you wanting to print to?  The debugger window, or are you running the tests from a console app and want to print to the actual console?

Comment: I would like to print out to whatever window that's most convenient. From what I see, the Output window seems the most convenient.

Comment: I just used Debug.Print().  In your Test Explorer (in VS) click on your test and on the bottom there should be a link named Output, click that

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Visual Studio with its built-in testing support, the output of `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` will go to the test results report. That is, after your test has run, double-click its entry in the Test Results list, and there will be a section called "Debug Trace" in the test run report.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, it would be most reasonable to call [TestContext.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.writeline(v=VS.100).aspx).  Here's [how to use a TestContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699.aspx).

---

Since I use TestDriven and NUnit, I just use `Console.WriteLine()` and the messages show when I run tests with the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I eventually found the solution.

Notice the **green check or red x** when you run the test in Visual Studio? Now click that and then click the link that says **output**.

That shows all the `Trace.WriteLine()`s for me, even when not in debug mode.